# Is there a way to extend PyEphem's satellite creation beyond 364 days?

Tags: pyephem, satellite-navigation

PyEphem doesn't allow one to create a satelllite for more than 364 days.
What would be the idea way to simulate a satellite for more than a year ?

I was trying to create a new satellite at the end of year and then somehow make their paths continuous. For that the "mean anomaly" has to be updated. Any suggestions how it can be done in PyEphem ?